# Bootstrap responsive parallax images overlapping

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, parallax

Currently I am working on a responsive template for my website. I am using the twitter bootstrap framework to create this template.

The parallax effect using the Jarallax plugin, since my website is responsive and my website is making use of **twitter bootstrap** I am having trouble putting 2 images on top of each other in a column (span4).

When using the background image as a div the background image is no correctly displayed on all screen sizes, so this is a responsive problem.

```
<img src="image-background.png" alt="bg" />
<img src="image-parallax.png" alt="fg" class="parallax-top" />
```

When scrolling the image parallax should change style and create the **parallax** effect.
**The problem** is I cannot get these images on top of each other in a way the template still is **responsive**.

Simple sample in the jsfiddle link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/nytrm/Z49Pv/3/

I hope to find a solution so I can still use the parallax and keep responsiveness.